# Best practice to receive JWT from third party provider?

Tags: express, cookies, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am playing with JWT and expressJS to learn something new, and come up with the idea to make my little JWT provider to use for all my future personal projects.

The idea is quite simple, my provider will register with facebook and twitter API, and will use passport to authenticate with them. I will also store users credentials so I don't need to worry about that in my other projects (these project will hold their info about users but various data from socials/passwords etc.. will be in the provider).

I coded this little workflow:

- I register the app in my provider with a callback url
- Put a button (e.g. 'Login with Twitter') on my project, that links directly to my provider
- when I accept the Twitter conditions, twitter callback calls my provider that pick the right user and redirect to my project.

I am stuck on this last point, I would love to pass to my project the JWT token to use for its next requests, but how do I pass to it?

Cannot set cookie because domains are different obviously, I am missing something? Did I follow the wrong way?

Comment: When the app needs to log in a user, it redirects user to your central login form, and you request user's credentials, or use Facebook/twitter. After a successful login you want to issue a JWT to the app, so it can use the API later. Is that so? do you want to implement an oauth2.0 server?

Comment: 0Yes I want to this @pedrofb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication flow you describe is similar to OAuth2. I suggest to read the [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). It explain the technical details to implement it. You can also refer to [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html). It is an extension of OAuth2 using JWT

Basically you need to create an access token after a successful login and return a redirection to the callback url. The adapted flow to your context could be the following

1. App redirects user to central login form
2. The server prompts user for the credentials :It returns an HTML form with the supported authentication methods, that can include a connection with a third party authentication provider
3. After a successful authentication, the server creates an access token. It can be a JWT
4. The server returns a redirection to the provided callback url. It includes an authentication code
5. The app request the authentication server using the previous code and get an access token
6. The token can be used by app to access to a protected resource

In Oauth2, the access token it is just a random string, but you can use JWT perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I am doing, but my doubts are about point `4. The server returns a redirection to the provided callback url. It includes an authentication code. ` The only way to pass the token in the callback is using url parameters. I am asking if this the best practice and if it is enough protect this exchange with SSL to be safe.

Comment: A redirection URL with parameters is the way defined in Oauth2 to send the authentication code. Supporgint TLS in the redirection URL is recommended but it is not mandatory (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-3.1.2.1). Note that the authentication code is not the access token. After this, it is needed to perform a new request to authorization server to get the access token. There, the server can request to client the credentials. So a attacker that steals an authentication code could not use it

Comment: But if one get the  authentication code , could ask my server and obtain the access one. To prevent this I need to make some sort of control on the origin of the request

Comment: The client MUST authenticate with the authorization server to recover the access token to avoid this case. You decide the method: credentials, client certificates, trusted ip's, etc.

Comment: @pedrfb obviously... but when talking about client, there is not way to have credentials that are not hard coded in the js, nothing that I am aware of at least!

Comment: Probably the best way is to whitelist the host that can send the authorization token and get the access one.. make sense to you? Anyway thanks for the help! It what I needed

Comment: No, credentials in the JS is not the purpose of the specification. The token must be retrieved on the server side of the client app where the credentials are sufficiently secure. Note that a redirection URI always point to a service

Comment: whitelist the host is an option if you know the ip address of the sender. But requires more configuration than provide credentials to each third party

Comment: One last thing, what exactly mean with this `Note that a redirection URI always point to a service`

Comment: I mean the callback URL provided by the app points to a server. There you can store the credentials to retrieve the access token